# How to create client for website?

Tags: android

I want try create simple client for website, I read information about WebView but don't understand how this begin work, maybe someone tell me where to start or recommend me some literature. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

write a webview in xml and then write a client inside activity

**IN ACTIVITY**

```
        // initialize web view
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.rss_webview);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new RssWebClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");


    public class RssWebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(FeedActivity.this, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

**IN XML**

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/rss_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 />
```